# How to eliminate odor from the heavy cooking?

Tags: kitchens

We live in a small space. And we cook a lot leaving our home smell like a spice box. 
What are the ways to follow while cooking to not spread the odor.. And secondly get rid of the smell fast.

Answer (score 1):

In some cultures, there is a room called a [spice kitchen](http://myconsumersvoice.com/all-articles/what-is-a-spice-kitchen/) that is an important feature of the house.

> In order for the Spice Kitchen to serve its intended purpose, it needs a high-volume exhaust hood over the oven and a door. The foods that are going to be prepared in the Spice Kitchen should be stored there as well, so there should be cabinetry, counter space and a sink.

Some foods create an enormous amount of smell and that smell can be carried around by steam or aerosolized oils or smoke.

So, the best solution is to get rid of the smell before it circulates and settles on other areas of the house.  You need a large hood to catch the steam and smoke from cooking and duct it out of the area.  How you do this is probably beyond the scope of your question, but removing the by-products of cooking is the solution.

Comment: Thank You. This information is useful. If we can afford.. we prolly will look for a spice kitchen in our next house.

Comment: @JamesKumo glad it was helpful, but my main point was to look at how spice kitchens are used and work to get an idea of how to “fix” your kitchen.  I’m not saying you need to move or that your current kitchen will never work.